# Text File Content Automation

Tags: linux, oracle

I am working on a system which runs on Oracle DB as front end and Uses Linux as Backend. For running the system i have a file called INIT.SQl which runs in Linux environment and contains the parameters which are passed to specific tables like:

```
a=current_month&year     :1215
b=current_month&year-1   :1115
```

[INIT.SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKieH.png)

so these parameters are passed to different tables for selecting data from them.
like table name abc_1215 and abc_1115

i am looking for an option to automate this process as every month i have to manually update the dates in the INIT.SQL file.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What does your init.sql file look like exactly? Can't you work with sysdate?

Comment: i am  working on a system which uses the current month as well as the historical data. So for that purpose every month i need to manually update the dates

Answer (score 0):

You could use bind variables instead and fill them how you want it to.

```
variable monthyear number;
exec :monthyear :=  to_char (sysdate, 'MM')|| to_char(sysdate, 'yy');
select :monthyear from dual;
```

Comment: i tried to run this syntax in oracle an it says bind variable monthyear is not declared.

Comment: Firstly when i run the first line to declare the bind variable it does not shows any output. And after that when i run the next two lines in the output i get a table with one column having null values

Comment: no output on declare is fine. the exec should give you "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".

Comment: I forgot a ; behind the exec statement in my answer, is that the problem?

Comment: In the Query result it says : Anonymous block completed and

Comment: i added it. But still the same

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot reconstruct the problem.